# trying to bring bootstrap buttons to the bottom right of the section, but it brings it outside the section instead. Why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So this is a bit puzzling.

```css
.features {
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #4A4A4A;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="features">

  <p class='new-question'>Placeholder text</p>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='bottom-right'>

      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-start'>Start</button>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-skip'>Skip</button>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

I just want the buttons to be displayed in a row at the bottom right of the feature section. But instead of doing that, they completely overshoot the section. Any ideas why?

This is what it looks like right now (ignore the text, I generated it with js):[image]

Comment: That's how absolute positioning works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.  If you aren't already using your browser's web inspector, it's a good place to learn about what's going on with your layout

Answer (score 6):

Add `position: relative` to `.features`.
Whenever you wants to move child element with `position: absolute` according to parent then adding `position: relative` to parent is necessary.

**For Absolute Position:**

> The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

```css
.features {
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #4A4A4A;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-right{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="features">

  <p class = 'new-question'> Placeholder text</p>
  <div class = 'bottom-right'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-start'>Start</button>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-skip'>Skip</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: right. I don't know why I missed that this time considering I did it plenty of times before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set `.features` to `position:relative`

```css
.features {
margin-top: 10px;
min-height: 400px;
border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
border-radius: 7px;
color: #4A4A4A;
overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.bottom-right{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;

}
```

```html
<section class="features">

            <p class = 'new-question'> Placeholder text</p>

            <div class='row'>
            <div class = 'bottom-right'>

            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-start'>Start</button>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-skip'>Skip</button>


            </div>
            </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `position:relative` on parent element

```css
.features {
margin-top: 10px;
min-height: 400px;
border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
border-radius: 7px;
color: #4A4A4A;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
}

.bottom-right{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;

}
```

```html
<section class="features">

            <p class = 'new-question'> Placeholder text</p>

            <div class='row'>
            <div class = 'bottom-right'>

            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-start'>Start</button>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large btn-skip'>Skip</button>


            </div>
            </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what position absolute does, you position an element relative to the next parent element with relative or absolute positioning. It will go all the way back to the html element itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself if there is no such parent.
So you need to add position relative to one of his parent, in your code you want to add it to the section features.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bottom-right{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This code worked for me but when I wanted to place a few of them around my website, they all ended up above the fold, on top of each other. To prevent that, I wrapped each section (including the bottom-right div) in a container, like this:

```
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">...{my code}...</div>
    <div class="bottom-right">...</div>
  </div>
</section>
```